# Heroku Rails deployment successful but Application Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

***Edited**

In trying to deploy my Rails 4 app onto Heroku, I kept getting error messages even though my deployment was successful. I also needed to translate my app from using sqlite3 to postgres (edits to database.yml) What helped me was running:

```
heroku logs -- myAppName
```

where as before, I was only doing:

```
heroku logs
```

An error I got was a MissingTemplate.
I found that I needed to update my production.rb file to include:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

and in my **Gemfile**

```
group :production, :staging do
    gem 'haml'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: **EDIT: 
Github: https://github.com/fhcheng/faye-website/

Comment: did you install `bundle`

Comment: try to this command `heroku run rake db:create`

Comment: @uzaif Hi thank you for responding. I have bundle in my vagrant VM environment but not on my computer. I just tried your suggestion but I am getting the same error. But I will add a section in my original question to include the logs after creating a db (i did not have this before)

Comment: check this app which i also deploy on heroku and also check its `database.yml` https://github.com/uzaif313/studentsdesk/

Comment: remove host option on `database.yml` file also check this https://github.com/uzaif313/studentsdesk/blob/master/config/database.yml

Comment: Hi, I am using postgresql instead of sqlite3 because heroku won't take it. Do you have a sample database.yml file using postgresql I can reference? thanks

Comment: yes but can you show my heroku logs

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior

Comment: I didn't have room to add another section, so I replaced my original heroku logs with the new ones. Thanks for looking into this @uzaif

Comment: i think problem cause is because you define same routes two times remove this one `get '/home', to: 'static_pages#home'`

Comment: I deleted the duplicate route (thanks for catching that), and I pushed and deployed but I still get the error when loading the herokuapp

Comment: try to run server in production in your local machine `rails server -e production`

Comment: did you check it in production?

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. As an update, I've cloned my project and fully converted it from sqlite3 to postgres so that should not be the problem. I have it running on the local server and it works @uzaif

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you! Posted updates to Q

Comment: what's an error now?

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy to announce that I was finally able to get this working! The problem was found by running: heroku logs -- appname

I needed to put haml in my production.rb file, and a few other tricky things were missing. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The 5th last line of your console log is giving you the answer :)

```
2016-07-23T03:03:41.316258+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'localhost' database is not configured. Available: ["host", "development", "test", "production"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

You can't use localhost on heroku. Try `production` instead

Comment: That was so quick, thank you for looking into this! This is my first time deploying from localhost to heroku so please bear with me -- could you explain how I would go ahead and change to 'production'?

Comment: its not cause any problem

Comment: Hi I tried your suggestions and now the original Application Error page is gone, but I get this now: "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information." I am going to put the new heroku logs in my original post

Comment: Ok cool. Are you able to deploy and start the server without errors?

Comment: I'm unable to add the updated heroku logs because i don't have enough room to post. But when I deploy, I do get this error: 

2016-07-23T03:47:54.603463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fayechengherokuapp.com request_id=ce656a8e-3c8e-409c-bd01-cc042bc6733d fwd="67.188.49.25" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=228

Comment: A status = 200 says that the request was OK, so it seems to have deployed ok - so that's not the error :)

Comment: I tried redoing the db:create and now I see this error:

Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "user"=>"faye", "password"=>nil, "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"my_database"}
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: I'd recommend having a read of the heroku documentation for rails connections with postgres, as it sounds like there's a few things going on here. Hope that helps :)

edit: for what it's worth, having a password set to `nil` is probably wrong too ;)